# Merge several rows into one if they have a gap less than a 5 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to find a SQL query that lets me to merge some rows into one from a table that have a gap less than 5 seconds. For example, I have a table like the following:

```
Name    |    Time
==============================
John       2021-02-01 13:08:10
John       2021-02-01 13:08:12
John       2021-02-01 17:35:23
John       2021-02-07 11:16:31
Walt       2021-01-14 10:23:48
Joseph     2021-01-23 07:04:33
Walt       2021-01-14 10:23:51
Walt       2021-01-04 09:22:45
```

So, I want to have a result like this:

```
Name    |    Time
==============================
John       2021-02-01
John       2021-02-01
John       2021-02-07
Walt       2021-01-14
Walt       2021-01-04
Joseph     2021-01-23
```

For John there are two rows that have a gap less than 5 seconds, so they will merge in one row for the same day. The same happens with Walt.

Can I do this with a SQL query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens to the time component?  What if there are multiple rows in row?

Comment: @DaleK if there are many rows, each less than 5s, there should only be one row with the current day of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the next date is within 5 seconds after the current row and if so - remove such a row. This can be achieved with [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) analytical function.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 'John'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-02-01 13:08:10', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'John'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-02-01 13:08:12', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'John'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-02-01 13:08:15', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'John'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-02-01 17:35:23', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'John'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-02-07 11:16:31', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'Walt'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-01-14 10:23:48', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'Joseph' as name, convert(datetime, '2021-01-23 07:04:33', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'Walt'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-01-14 10:23:51', 120) as dt union all
>   select 'Walt'   as name, convert(datetime, '2021-01-04 09:22:45', 120) as dt
> )
> , gap_size as (
>   select
>     name,
>     dt,
>     /*Check the difference between current row and the next row per name*/
>     datediff(s,
>       dt,
>       lead(dt) over(partition by name order by dt asc)
>     ) as within_5_secs_with_next
>   from a
> )
> select
>   name,
>   cast(dt as date) as dt_date
> from gap_size
> where coalesce(within_5_secs_with_next, 10) >= 5
> order by name, dt asc
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name   | dt_date   
> :----- | :---------
> John   | 2021-02-01
> John   | 2021-02-01
> John   | 2021-02-07
> Joseph | 2021-01-23
> Walt   | 2021-01-04
> Walt   | 2021-01-14
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0f3460e58bc4e4f8a4aefe0a4cb645a9)*

Comment: this is just what I was looking for. Thank you very much @astentx